# Automatically ordered columns plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, plugins

A while ago I found a jQuery (I think) script.

- It take floated li items (columns) and fit them together.
- A normal floated list (with li as columns) creates gaps. This plugin automatically fill those gaps.
- It's a column plugin. Like a gallery.

What is the plugin name? or URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/).  Either way, Masonry could be adapted to this task.

The [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin/) is another possibility that offers similar functionality.